# double datatype in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am defining my column's length as `double(16,2)`. Here 16 is not fixed. But 2 is fixed. Display length will vary depending on calculation. So I want to make it variable length.

How do I define the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (i.e. 2 from my example) but have display length variable? Because I don't want to occupy unnecessary space.

Comment: I think you're confusing data storage with data display

Answer (score 6):

The FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values.

**MySQL uses four bytes for single-precision values and eight bytes for double-precision values.**

MySQL also supports this optional precision specification, but **the precision value is used only to determine storage size. A precision from 0 to 23 results in a 4-byte single-precision FLOAT column. A precision from 24 to 53 results in an 8-byte double-precision DOUBLE column.**

MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D). Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.

**FLOAT:**

A small (single-precision) floating-point number. Permissible values are -3.402823466E+38 to -1.175494351E-38, 0, and 1.175494351E-38 to 3.402823466E+38. These are the theoretical limits, based on the IEEE standard. The actual range might be slightly smaller depending on your hardware or operating system. 
 A single-precision floating-point number is accurate to approximately 7 decimal places. 
This is not required and will default to **10,2,**
     (If M and D are omitted, values are stored to the limits permitted by the hardware.)

**DOUBLE:**

M is the total number of digits and D is the number of digits following the decimal point. If M and D are omitted, values are stored to the limits permitted by the hardware. A double-precision floating-point number is accurate to approximately 15 decimal places. 
This is not required and will default to **16,4**, where 4 is the number of decimals. 
( If M and D are omitted, values are stored to the limits permitted by the hardware. )

For more
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL `DOUBLE` data type [occupies 8 bytes of storage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-numeric) no matter what numbers you store in it.